# Pronunciation of "quel"

Tags: prononciation

I'm not sure if I'm pronouncing this right. Does the first syllable of quel sound like "gel" or "kel"? In the alphabet, q makes a koo sound.

Comment: Listening to a native speaker say the word is often a good first step when not sure how to say a word. [Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/index.php) is a multilingual database of audio recordings of words and sentences all recorded by natives (no robots).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IPA transcription of *quel* is [kɛl]. The consonant *k* in French is *unaspirated* and *unvoiced*.

This is in opposition to *g* as in *goût* [gu], which is unaspirated and *voiced*.

I am guessing from your name that your mother tongue is Chinese, but if I am wrong please correct me.

In Putonghua, the opposition between the syllables *ka* [kʰa] (unvoiced and aspirated) and *ga* [ka] (unvoiced and unaspirated) is one of aspiration and not voicing. The difficulty here is that Putonghua *ga* is variably realized with some voicing as [ga] ([see here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/does-mandarin-chinese-have-phonetically-voiced-plosives-fricatives-or-affricat/4862#4862)).

In summary, French *k* is like an unvoiced realization of Pinyin *g*, while French *g* is like a voiced realization of Pinyin *g*. To a speaker of Putonghua, French *k* and *g* both sound like Pinyin *g*.